# Apply style to span for displaying it at particular position

Tags: html, css

Here is one div which contains multiple span element.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
      .content{
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 250px; 
        padding: 5px; 
      }

      .name{                
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #efa520;
        padding: 2px;
      }

      .address{
        padding: 2px;
        color: #c14a1b;
      }

      .date{
        padding: 2px;
        color: #a78919;
      }

      .ids{
        padding: 2px;
        color: #1b8ac1;            
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="content">
      <span class="name">Christopher Brown</span><br>
      <span class="address">Washington</span><br>
      <span class="date">01/11/1987</span><br>
      <span class="ids">203459867</span><br>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

I want the last one span which is present with class name '.ids' in front of first span (i.e. at right side upper corner of div) using only CSS. Without changing or adding any HTML element, I want this change. But you can remove only `<br>` HTML element, if it is necessary but maintain the same structure as it is displaying now.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a flex layout with `order`. Obviously, removing `<br>` or display none.

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.ids {
  order: -1;
}
.name {
  order: -2;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.name {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #efa520;
  padding: 2px;
}
.address {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #c14a1b;
}
.date {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #a78919;
}
.ids {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #1b8ac1;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.ids {
  order: -1;
}
.name {
  order: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span class="name">Christopher Brown</span>
  <span class="address">Washington</span>
  <span class="date">01/11/1987</span>
  <span class="ids">203459867</span>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: updated preview]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and help. But applying this style, the last span is going before first span, not in front of first one. I want last span in front of first span.

Comment: @Pooja So you want it to be after Christopher Brown, is it?

Comment: Yes. Please help for the same

Comment: @Pooja Add this as well: `.name {
  order: -2;
}` At the end. [**Preview**](http://output.jsbin.com/hilaqoxaku)

Comment: Still this is not giving expected output.

Comment: @Pooja I have added the output screen shot. See if that's what you need? Can you please **reload / refresh** and see? Check this site:  [**Preview**](http://output.jsbin.com/hilaqoxaku)